# Form Select List - Initially selected option not working correctly in IE

Tags: html, internet-explorer, forms

I have a form with a select list of various office locations, i have it set so it should have the office initially selected BUT it does not seem to Work in IE!!! (no surprise)

here is what i am using to preselect:

```
<option selected value="Office 1">Office 1</option>
```

here is the site: http://www.nwtaxpreparation.com/offices/122andpowell.html

let me know if you have any solutions!

Answer (score 5):

HTML 4 uses:

```
<option value="foo" selected>Bar</option>
```

XHTML REQUIRES:

```
<option value="foo" selected="selected">Bar</option>
```

To say that "there is no such thing as selected="whatever" is false!

Answer (score 2):

I recently had the same problem with selected options tags. I had a series of select boxes like this:

```
<select>
        <option value="dr">Day rate</option>
        <option selected="selected" value="sv">Social value</option>
</select>   

<select>
        <option value="dr">Day rate</option>
        <option selected="selected" value="sv">Social value</option>
</select>
```

I couldn't work out why the correct items wouldn't select. I later discovered that it was because there was no name attribute on the select item. Firefox seems to need this to work properly, even in version 15.

```
<select name="type">
        <option value="dr">Day rate</option>
        <option selected="selected" value="sv">Social value</option>
</select>
```

I changed it to the above and selected="selected" works fine now.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the problem with the name attribute. That helped!